# Is there an opposite of the "IN" function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
Select
Sysdate,Sum(Count(P.Init_Dtime))
From Player p,player_source ps
Where
Ps.Group_Id In (44,9,42,15,23,73,45,33,69,63,7,49,96,81,28,57,98,74,92,38) 
And P.Player_Id=Ps.Player_Id 
and
Trunc(p.Init_Dtime) > Trunc(Sysdate) - 7 
And
Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-mar-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
And Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) < To_Date('2015-sep-9','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group By Trunc(P.Init_Dtime)
Order By Trunc(P.Init_Dtime) Asc
```

I am using the "IN" function to include only Group_IDs that have certain numbers. The Group_ID column can have a value from 1-100. How do I change this query so the result includes all Group_Id numbers that are not (44,9,42,15,23,73,45,33,69,63,7,49,96,81,28,57,98,74,92,38)?

Comment: FYI - `IN` is an operator, not a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Peter wrote, using the **"NOT IN"** is the real answer.
*The question is why you are using this list as a list*...
I assumed that this list have some meaning and that you may have few lists like this that "grouped" some groups together.
 If this is the case, you may want to have **another table** with those groups and do a **join** between `Ps.Group_Id` and this new table...

---

Edit:
On another note, If you have indexs on `p.Init_Dtime` or on  `P.Create_Dtime`, **Oracle can not use those indexes** because you are using those columns inside a function.
You might want to consider how to work without a function (you can add 2 more columns that will hold the truncate values for those column, indexed them as well and use them on the query)

---

Edit2:
If you want a quick and dirty replacing of the list with information from a table, just remember that you can use **`select`** inside the **`not in`** part.
If you have table `t1` with col `Group_Id` and col `Valid_Groups`, you can do:

```
... Where 
    Ps.Group_Id In (Select Group_Id from T1 where Valid_Groups = 'true') And ...
```

Same goes to "**not in**" ...

Comment: It may be a case of dynamic sql and the list he's querying on could be group ids already processed somehow.

Comment: @PeterDavidsen, More than agree... just wanted to make sure he can see the other options in case it is not a dynamic data from other processing :)  (I assume novice level of knowledge, based on the question)

Comment: Exactly, and good point about using columns in a function that may or may not have an index.

Comment: Zack, I agree, I was trying to figure out the join but for the purposes of my time I was going with the quick fix. I'd love to work with you to get the join statement going so I can use it for this and future situations...let me know if you are up for it and ill provide details!

Answer (score 9):

You can use NOT to negate the expression.

So you could say :

```
Where
Ps.Group_Id NOT IN (44,9 ...)
```